# getting error in while saving the data into database by sending data via a post request

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

**what I am Trying to do :
I am trying to save the data into database by sending data via a post request**
please try to help when I am using similar code it is working but when I am copy pasting same code into this file its not working and showing same error
**code of connecting database and model**

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const validator=require('validator');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/task-manager-api',{
    useNewUrlParser:true,
}).then(()=>{
    console.log("connection successful");
}).catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error);
})


const Task=mongoose.model('Task',{
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true,// making  name compulsory to be entered 
        trim:true // trim will remove spaces
    },
    completion:{
        type:Boolean,
        required:true
    }
})
// const me = new Task({
//         name:'packing',
//         completion:false
//     })
//     me.save().then(()=>{
//         console.log(me)
//     }).catch((error)=>{
//         console.log(error);
//     })
module.exports=Task
```

**the json needed to be saved**

```
{
    "name":"washing",
    "completion":true
}
```

**error while sending json via post**

```
    {
  "errors": {
    "completion": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "Path `completion` is required.",
      "properties": {
        "message": "Path `completion` is required.",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "completion"
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "completion"
    },
    "name": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "Path `name` is required.",
      "properties": {
        "message": "Path `name` is required.",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "name"
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "name"
    }
  },
  "_message": "Task validation failed",
  "name": "ValidationError",
  "message": "Task validation failed: completion: Path `completion` is required., name: Path `name` is required."
}
```

**Router File**

```
    const express =require('express');
const router=new express.Router();
const Task =require('../2-mongoose/4-task');

router.get('/tasks' ,async(req,res)=>{
    const data = await Task.find({})
    res.send(data);
    // console.log(data);
})
router.get('/tasks/:name',async(req,res)=>{
    const dataname= await Task.find({name:req.params.name});
    res.send(dataname);
    // console.log(req.params);
})
router.post('/tasks',async(req,res)=>{
    const task=new Task(req.body);
    try{
        await task.save();
        console.log(req.body)
        res.status(201).send(task);
    }
    catch(err){
        res.status(404).send(err);
    }
})
module.exports=router
```

**and the main file**

```
  const express=require('express');
const app=express();
const router=require('../4-task-routers/task');

app.use(router);
app.use(express.json());

app.listen(8000,()=>{
    console.log('server started broo');
})
```

Comment: Please read [ask], provide a [mcve], and do some debugging. The error message says that completion and name a missing, so the data you are sending doesn’t match the data you think you are sending.

Comment: this has nothing related to routes of post...Please show how you are sending data and how your routes are handeling it

Comment: Indeed, you need to show the (express?) route handler for the post request and how you're trying to create and insert the task.

Comment: edited question with index and router file

Comment: You can't learn this way. Go to the "similar code", study it, find out why it's working, then apply it to your project. Blindly copy won't benefit you